# How do I stop the first call of a function from executing if the function is called again?

Tags: javascript

I have a section of DIV elements in HTML that are a set of cards. `onmouseenter`, depending on the card you're on, the cards animate to move out of the way in order to view the cards underneath (They're stacked on top of eachother and offset to actually allow a `mouseenter`).

The problem is that if I move too fast, the function begins to execute both the element I moved fast over, and the element that the mouse is currently on. It becomes a loop and the card animations begin to flash repeatedly.

What needs to happen, is if I move too fast over an element and move to the next, the element that the mouse is actually on needs to trigger, and not the element that I moved quickly over. Here's the functions that control both `onleave` and enter:

```
var siblings = [];
var siblingsLen;

function toggleCards(objId) {
  var grabId = objId.id;
  let checkPos = document.getElementById(grabId).previousElementSibling;
  let i = 0;

  if (checkPos == null) {
    return;
  } else {
    for (i = 0;; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        siblings.push(document.getElementById(grabId).previousElementSibling);
      } else {
        siblings.push(document.getElementById(siblings[i - 1].id).previousElementSibling);
      }
      if (siblings[i].previousElementSibling == null) {
        siblingsLen = siblings.length;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < siblingsLen; i++) {
    document.getElementById(siblings[i].id).classList.add('cardAnimationForwards');
    if (document.getElementById(siblings[i].id).classList.contains('cardAnimationBackwards')) {
      document.getElementById(siblings[i].id).classList.remove('cardAnimationBackwards');
    }
  }
}

function toggleCardsLeave() {
  for (i = 0; i < siblingsLen; i++) {
    document.getElementById(siblings[i].id).classList.remove('cardAnimationForwards');
    document.getElementById(siblings[i].id).classList.add('cardAnimationBackwards');
  }
  siblingsLen = 0;
  siblings = [];
}
```

Also, I've only ever done coding as a hobby, and not in classes or anything, so if there's anything you see that you could give me suggestions on, that'd be great! Thank you for your time, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aa @SaurabhGhewari stated, you should use debounce or throttle methods. Lodash is a great library, i recommend it, but since i see you are using only javascript.

From this tutorial: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Try adding this function to your code:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

And in your code

```
var toggleCards = debounce(function(object) {
    // All the code from your function
}, 250);
```

Change the time parameter according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much. And to you as well @SaurabhGhewari. I knew from the beginning that it would have to be some sort of timing function, I just wasn't sure how to implement it. I greatly appreciate the help given, and hope to give back as y'all have done for me! Cheers!

Comment: Glad to be Helpful !

Comment: Same here. Always glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the Debounce or Throttle methods of lodash. And if you dont want to use Lodash, then you need to implement the concept of debounce and throttle. Here is the documentation and explanation

[Debounce and Throttle using Javascript](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf)